# Getting windows ‘ShFileOperation’ API to recursively delete files in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am using the following code to delete a large number of files

```
function FastDelete(const fromDir: string): Boolean;
var
  fos: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@fos, SizeOf(fos));
  with fos do
  begin
    wFunc := FO_DELETE;
    fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY or
              FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or
              FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS or
              FOF_NOERRORUI or
              FOF_NO_UI;
    pFrom := PChar(fromDir+'\*.*' + #0);
  end;
  Result := (0 = ShFileOperation(fos));
end;
```

How do I get it to recursively delete all the files in the path?

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795(VS.85).aspx)

**EDIT**

The problem is the **FOF_FILESONLY** flag
After removing it files are recursively deleted

Answer (score 4):

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795.aspx):

> **FOF_NORECURSION**
>
> Only perform the operation in the local directory. Don't operate recursively into subdirectories, **which is the default behavior**.

Looks like that's your answer right there.  It should recurse automatically unless you ask it not to.

EDIT: Looks like there's a problem with your flags.  You need to **OR** them together, not add them together.  Since `FOF_NO_UI` already includes `FOF_NOERRORUI`, adding it again can change the value, and you might be accidentally adding some things together that add up to `FOF_NORECURSION`.  It should look like this:

```
    fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY or
              FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or
              FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS or
              FOF_NOERRORUI or
              FOF_NO_UI;
```

Comment: Hi Mason - I am not using FOF_NORECURSION how should I change my code to make it recursively delete the files in the subdirectories ?

Comment: Also, not really sure if the '\*.*' mask is necessary if you are deleting the entire directory. Passing the function the directory itself should be enough

Comment: Eagle, it depends on whether you want to delete the directory or just its contents.

Comment: Adding a all the flags gives an answer of $2A96 and FOF_NORECURSION = $1000 Thus FOF_NORECURSION has not been enabled

Comment: Adding or ORing bitmapped flags leads to the same result. OR is often called "logical sum".

Comment: Not when one of the flags overlaps another, as is the case here.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy - Roger that, its just that as I understand it, and as @Mason Wheeler suggests, when you specify the "all" mask "*.*" it will delete all the files, but not the sub-directories, which is what he needs (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to keep the directory also? If not you could just pass

```
pFrom := PChar(fromDir+#0);
```

Another option is to build a list of #0-delimited file-paths, and pass that with an extra #0, from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795(VS.85).aspx):

> Although this member is declared as a null-terminated string, it is used as a buffer to hold multiple file names. Each file name must be terminated by a single NULL character. An additional NULL character must be appended to the end of the final name to indicate the end of pFrom.

Comment: Very true, otherwise some `EOSError` will happen in `ShFileOperation`, at least in some random cases.