# Exclude only all files with specific mask recursively using SHFileOperation

Tags: file, delphi

I'd like to remove all files with a specific mask, like `*.tmp` or `*.log`, using `SHFileOperation()`.

So, I think some thing like this:

```
Function SpeedDelFile(const fromDir, Mask: string): Boolean;
var
  FosFile: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@FosFile, SizeOf(FosFile));
  with FosFile do
  begin
    wFunction := FO_DELETE;
    fFlags := FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS or
               FOF_NOERRORUI;
    pFrom := PChar(fromDir+'\'+Mask + #0);
  end;
  Result := (0 = ShFileOperation(FosFile));
end;
```

Using:

```
SpeedDelFile('C:\Users\%HomePath%\AppData\Local\Temp', '*.log');
```

The files in `C:\Users\%HomePath%\AppData\Local\Temp\` are removed, but not exclude files inside subfolders in `C:\Users\%HomePath%\AppData\Local\Temp\`.

I don't wanna remove any subfolders inside `C:\Users\%HomePath%\AppData\Local\Temp\`.

I know about `FindFirst()`/`FindNext()`, but these functions are so slow, terrible, that however it does not meet my expectations.

Any idea how I can adjust my code above?

Comment: Please learn to format the code in your posts. When you paste it in, select it all and either use Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button on the toolbar. There is a help button above the top right corner of the text area when you're writing your question that has details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591388/getting-windows-shfileoperation-api-to-recursively-delete-files-in-delphi

Comment: Sorry! Ok. I will more pay attention the next time.

Comment: You have to walk the directory tree